Monitoring general bandwidth peeks
I'm looking for an application that would help me figure out how often I hit the limit of my internet connection either with the down- or upload to see whether it would make sense to upgrade it to higher speeds.
This means I'm not interested in how much data flows through my cables, but rather how often and for how long I max out my internet connection.
It would be great if it could collect this kind of information over several weeks or months.

Why. If its slow, upgrade it?  OTOH, a decent router should give you some stats

@RohitGupta it looks like I don't have a decent router. It doesn't give me these kind of insights. Well, the purpose of this exercise is to find out whether it's slow or rather how ofter it is ;-]
